# Selecting best data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

```
Name - Code (String)
A    - 123
B    - 123 
C    - 23
D    - 123
E    - 23
F    - 23
G    - 66
H    - 66
```

What's the best data structure to represent this data. Names should be able to iterate easily.

**Edit**

Names are unique.
What's needed to be done is something like this. 
Had doubts in using Hashmap that why I asked.
**Code is a STRING**

```
for( loop dataStructure names (lets say n)){ 
   if(NAME.equals(n){
     String code = dataStructure.get(n);
     do somthing 
   }
}
```

Comment: are the names unique?

Comment: Depends on what you want to *do* with the data. Do you want to make lookups from name to code? Do you want to make lookups from code to lists of possible names? Do you want to iterate over name/code pairs?

Comment: Please clarify precisely _what_ you want to do with the data.

Comment: If anybody downvote this please be kind enough to mention the reason. So everybody can learn how to post a better question.

Comment: I would like to know also. Sometimes I think SO downvotes questions a little bit ti harsh. Maybe you could improve your question by adding why you fear a map is not a good solution. But otherwise, IDK.

Answer (score 5):

If the names are unique, a HashMap woulrd be apropriate.

You can iterate over the keys with `keys()`.

To iterate over the entries you can iterate over the `entrySet()`. 
See the JavaDoc of [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

If you need to perform a reverse lookup you could use the [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) from Guava. (General a very good library)

Map entries example:

```
public final class MapExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", "123");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
      if (mapEntry.getKey().equals("A")) {
        final String code = mapEntry.getValue();
        System.out.println("Your desired code: " + code);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

But since NAME seems to be a constant, you could simple do `String code = map.get(NAME)`?

Comment: Not if OP wants to efficiently iterate over name / code pair for instance. Then a `List<Pair<String, Integer>>` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @aioobe What is wrong with iterating over a `HashMap`?  But I agree that if reverse lookup is a possibility, then he would be better of using a Guava BiMap or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Specifically, if the order of the names is important, you can use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

You can populate it with the `put` method, and then iterate over the entries (or just the keys, or just the values):

```
// Fill the map:
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("A", "123");
map.put("B", "123");
// etc...

// Iterate over it:
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.pritnln ("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

EDIT:
If the order is not important, as noted in later edits to the OP, a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) would do just fine.

Note, however, that if you're looking for a specific key, like stated in the example in the OP, there's no point in looping over the keys - you just need to use `get` or `containsKey`:

```
String name = ...;
String code = map.get(name);
if (code != null) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: Why benefit would a `TreeMap` offer over a `HashMap` based on what the OP has said?

Comment: order of the name is not important

Comment: @AsiriLiyanaArachchi so  a `HashMap` will do just fine - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks you are considering this:

```
public enum Code {
    A("123"),
    B("123"), 
    C("23"),
    D("123"),
    E("23"),
    F("23"),
    G("66"),
    H("66");

    final public String value;

    Code(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

String h = Code.H.value;

for (Code code : Code.values()) {
    System.out.printf("Name %s, code %s%n", code, code.value);
}
```

Comment: The only flaw with this is that it isn't dynamic, an actual data structure may fit better.